# Write a trigger to update the records of Contact object(child) from Account object(parent) whenever we select a value in picklist

Tags: apex, trigger

Object:
Contact (child)
Account (Parent)

In Account object, there is pickup list field. Values: A,B,C,D.

- If we select A, then in contact object all the fields should be automatically update to A.
- If we select B, then in contact object all the fields should be automatically update to B.
- Similarly with other values.

(Through process builder it is possible. But I want to do it through code.)

## How to achieve this using trigger?

I have tried below code. Can anyone please help me, if the below code is correct or not?

```
trigger UpdateRecords on Account(after insert,after update) {
  Map<Id,Contact> childOpp = new Map<ID, Contact>();
  List<Id> myListId = new List<Id>();

  for (Account parentObj : Trigger.new) {
    myListId.add(parentObj.Contact);
  }

  childOpp = new Map<ID, Contact>
            ([SELECT id, Updated_Data__c,(SELECT ID, Option__c FROM Account) FROM Contact WHERE ID IN : myListId]);

  for (Account acc: Trigger.new){
     Contact mychildOpp =  childOpp.get(acc.Contact);
     mychildOpp.Updated_Data__c = acc.Option__c;
  }

  update  childOpp.values();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: If you're new to writing triggers, I recommend the [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro) Trailhead module - it'll help you get started.

Comment: Thank you Adrian Larson and David Reed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need a formula field on Contact that refers to `Account.yourPickupList`. A trigger is not useful.

Also you should not name "childOpp" a list that represents contacts. I guess it's a copy/paste but it's how you write unreadable code. And your sub-request `SELECT ID, Option__c FROM Account` is useless, you'll notice you don't use it.